# Omit path in PowerShell help for script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

When I call `Get-Help My-Script.ps1 -Full`, the name of my script is always displayed prepended by the full path to the script.

This is very ugly and distracting from the truely important information I provide in my help text.

Is there an option to have `Get-Help` only display the script name - without path - perhaps only prepended by `.\`?

#### Edit

Here's an example CmdLet:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS

Initializes installation specific configuration data.

.DESCRIPTION

Updates rows in the database table.

.PARAMETER DataRootPath

Root path of runtime data to be stored.

.PARAMETER WebApiBaseUrl

Base path of Web API.
#>
```

Then, wenn I request help on my CmdLet, I get the following output:

```
PS D:\Documents\Visual Studio-Projekte\Installation\2 - IIS Setup> get-help .\Configure-IIS.ps1 -Full 


NAME
    D:\Documents\Visual Studio-Projekte\Installation\2 - IIS Setup\Configure-IIS.ps1

SYNOPSIS
    Initializes installation specific configuration data.

    
SYNTAX
    D:\Documents\Visual Studio-Projekte\Installation\2 - IIS Setup\Configure-IIS.ps1 [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    Updates rows in the database table.


PARAMETERS
    <CommonParameters>
        This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug,
        ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable,
        OutBuffer, PipelineVariable, and OutVariable. For more information, see
        about_CommonParameters (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216).

INPUTS

OUTPUTS


RELATED LINKS
```

I'd rather like to get this (please notice the difference in the NAME and SYNTAX sections):

```
PS D:\Documents\Visual Studio-Projekte\Installation\2 - IIS Setup> get-help .\Configure-IIS.ps1 -Full 


NAME
    .\Configure-IIS.ps1

SYNOPSIS
    Initializes installation specific configuration data.

    
SYNTAX
    .\Configure-IIS.ps1 [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    Updates rows in the database table.


PARAMETERS
    <CommonParameters>
        This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug,
        ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable,
        OutBuffer, PipelineVariable, and OutVariable. For more information, see
        about_CommonParameters (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216).

INPUTS

OUTPUTS


RELATED LINKS
```

Comment: Are you talking about the current directory your on? Can you show us an example of the output. It shouldn't prepend anything if the script had been loaded.

Comment: Please pardon my late reply. I now updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Convert your My-Script.ps1 script to a My-Script.psm1 module, Import-Module My-Script.psm1, then call Get-Help My-Script -Full.  No more path.